# Uniqueness of svm solution

Tags: svm

How does one show that if the solution of the primal linear SVM is unique, then there exists a support vector whose corresponding slack variable is equal to $0$?

I tried showing this through proof by contradiction i.e., suppose for all support vectors, the corresponding slack variables are greater than 0. this would yield a solution that contradicts the uniqueness of the solution.

What I've shown so far is that if we assume that all the slack variables corresponding to the support vectors is $>0$, then this means all support vectors $\alpha_{i} = C$, where $C$ is the penalty on the slack variables.

I then find that $1^{T}y=0$ i.e., the sum of the labels of the support vectors has to be $0$ $\Rightarrow $ the number of positive and negative support vectors have to be equal. This doesn't have to be true for the dataset so this constraint may not hold. But this doesn't yield the desired contradiction.